# iPhone framework three20

Tags: iphone, objective-c, three20

What's the best way to customize the Table Items to include two images. I'd like to set one as a background with another layered above it along with text.

Any help is much appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

You can do this by creating a UITableViewCell in a seperate NIB file.

Go through this tutorial, it may help: http://bill.dudney.net/roller/objc/entry/uitableview_from_a_nib_file